# Invalid client error, I am using personal Gmail account

Tags: r, google-people-api

I am getting a 401 invalid_client error when I run the google calendar API code in R. I am using my personal Gmail account.

[image: Error 401: invalid_client]

The code is:

```r
options(
  googlecalendar.client_key = "xx",
  googlecalendar.client_secret = "yy"
)
```

where `xx` and `yy` are client keys and client secret ,respectively, copied from the google cloud.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: also this might not be a programming issue but rather more a gmail security/access problem. you may have to adapt the settings to allow access via r (or any other) scripts